# Stoltenberg told a news conference at NATO headquarters - why is there no the in front of NATO headquarters?

Tags: grammar, articles

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/nato-gets-chief-one-putin-may-approve-092336889.html

> Stoltenberg told a news conference **at NATO headquarters** that his three priorities are to "keep NATO strong. Help keep our neighborhood stable by working with partners. And keep the bond between Europe and North America rock solid."

Wouldn't **at the NATO headquarters** sound better?

Comment: The anarthrous form prevails in literature for some reason: 
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+NATO+headquarters%2C+at+the+NATO+headquarters&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20NATO%20headquarters%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20NATO%20headquarters%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The same is true for (the?) UN headquarters: 
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+UN+headquarters%2Cat+the+UN+headquarters&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20UN%20headquarters%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20UN%20headquarters%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether it sounds "better" is a matter of opinion; the difference between "NATO headquarters" and "the NATO headquarters" in my view is that the former uses "NATO headquarters" as the *name* of a specific part of NATO, namely, the headquarters building (or the headquarters campus, or the headquarters location - I don't know enough about NATO to say which). This is similar to military terms such as "Central Command".
By contrast, using "the NATO headquarters" implies that there were potentially multiple headquarters he could have spoken at, and he simply happened to speak at NATO's.

Or, the somewhat shorter version:
"NATO headquarters" is being used as a name, here, and names don't usually get articles.

Answer (score 3):

I would venture to say that the reason why there is no definite article here ("at NATO headquarters" rather than "at the NATO headquarters") has to do with the locative force of the preposition "at".

The locative preposition "at" wants to be followed by a reference to a specific place, not by an expression that refers to a meta-property of a place, such as its "the-ness".

He is *at Harvard University* not *at the Harvard University*.

They are stationed *at headquarters* not *at the headquarters*.

You might say, what about "**They are at the summit of Mount Everest**".  There, "are at" means "have attained", that is, it refers to a *destination*, which is not the same as a *locus*.